# Updating state with immutability helper update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutability

I want to update my state with the immutability-helper function *update* (https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper)

```
state = {
    field: '',
    items: ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4', 'Item 5', 'Item 6']
  };

addElementToList() {
 const i = this.state.items.length;
 const newState = ()=> {
  update(this.state,
    {
      items: {
        $push: [
          {
            [i]: this.state.field
          }
        ]
      }
     }
   )
 };
 this.setState = newState;
}
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error when the function is executed.

```
Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _immutabilityHelper.update) is not a function
```

What have I missed,any thoughts about this?

Comment: Isn't it easier to just use JavaScript's `Array.prototype.concat` (or spread syntax) and `Array.prototype.slice` to add/remove elements from an array without mutations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know the OP asked for an answer about using this 3rd party library but the original code snippet for this library produced code with an *aesthetic* that is similar to callback-hell: specifically the use of a lot of nested braces *and* curly braces.

As a result I just wanted to weigh in on how to achieve the same *unmutated* state using JavaScript's [**`Array.prototype.concat`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) instead.

You *may* find that the following approaches are cleaner and more succinct.

#### Using Array.prototype.concat:

```
addElementToList() {
  const i = this.state.items.length;
  const   newState = ()=> { 
    items: this.state.items.concat([this.state.field]);
  }
  this.setState = newState;
}
```

#### Using ES6 spread syntax:

```
addElementToList() {
  const i = this.state.items.length;
  const   newState = ()=> { 
    items: [...this.state.items, this.state.field];
  }
  this.setState = newState;
}
```

---

#### Original OP code snippet for comparison:

*it uses immutability helper library (https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper)*

```
addElementToList() {
  const i = this.state.items.length;
  const newState = ()=> {
    update(this.state,
      {
         items: {
           $push: [
              {
                 [i]: this.state.field
              }
           ]
        }
      }
    )
  };
  this.setState = newState;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the spread operator worked for me. Looks a lot cleaner, too.